# php calendar with previous and next not reloading the page

Tags: php, calendar, sidebar

I need to include a php calendar on the sidebar of my page.

I am using a snippet I found weeks ago, as I have used it before and it works fine. But this time, I have to add next and previous buttons to display the previous or next month...

My question is... do I need to modify the php that generates the current month?

this is what I have so far:

```
    <table class="month">
    <tr class="days">
        <td>Mon</td>
        <td>Tues</td>
        <td>Wed</td>
        <td>Thurs</td>
        <td>Fri</td>
        <td>Sat</td>
        <td>Sun</td>
    </tr>
        <?php 

    $today = date("d"); // Current day
    $month = date("m"); // Current month
    $year = date("Y"); // Current year
    $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year); // Days in current month

    $lastmonth = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$month-1,1,$year)); // Days in previous month

    $start = date("N", mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)); // Starting day of current month
    $finish = date("N", mktime(0,0,0,$month,$days,$year)); // Finishing day of  current month
    $laststart = $start - 1; // Days of previous month in calander

    $counter = 1;
    $nextMonthCounter = 1;

    if($start > 5){ $rows = 6; }else {$rows = 5; }

    for($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++){
        echo '<tr class="week">';
        for($x = 1; $x <= 7; $x++){             

            if(($counter - $start) < 0){
                $date = (($lastmonth - $laststart) + $counter);
                $class = 'class="blur"';
            }else if(($counter - $start) >= $days){
                $date = ($nextMonthCounter);
                $nextMonthCounter++;

                $class = 'class="blur"';

            }else {
                $date = ($counter - $start + 1);
                if($today == $counter - $start + 1){
                    $class = 'class="today"';
                }
            }


            echo '<td '.$class.'><span class="dayWrap">'. $date . '</span></td>';

            $counter++;
            $class = '';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }

?>
</table>
  <div class="changeMonthLinks">
  <a class="col-xs-12" href="">< Prev</a>
  <a class="col-xs-12 aright" href="">Next ></a>
  </div>
```

I just don't know how to proceed...or what do I need to add in the anchor tags :S

Any help will be appreciate it.

Thank you
Thank you!!

Comment: Question is do you want the page to reload when this sidebar calendar is updated?

Comment: ideally no!! but I guess I will need to do it with ajax and it is even more difficult for me :(

Comment: There are a number of good client side (js/jquery) calendar "frameworks" out there that can help with that. Ajax is not as complicated as it comes off being especially with jquery. It helps give a better user experience as well so totally worth picking up if you can dedicate a couple hours to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added $now for the param ?now in the url and I'm parsing it with strtotime to the variable $dtNow, all the date functions are extended and the links in the bottom are extended with ?now=$dtNow + 1 month and ?now=$dtNow - month

Here's the code

```php
<?php

$now = '';
if(isset($_GET['now']))
    $now = $_GET['now'];

$dtNow = strtotime($now);
if(!$dtNow)
{
    $dtNow = time();
}
echo "<h1>Today is " . date('Y-m-d', $dtNow) . "</h1>";

?>
<table class="month">
    <tr class="days">
        <td>Mon</td>
        <td>Tues</td>
        <td>Wed</td>
        <td>Thurs</td>
        <td>Fri</td>
        <td>Sat</td>
        <td>Sun</td>
    </tr>
    <?php


    $today = date("d", $dtNow); // Current day
    $month = date("m", $dtNow); // Current month
    $year = date("Y", $dtNow); // Current year
    $days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year); // Days in current month

    $lastmonth = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$month-1,1,$year)); // Days in previous month

    $start = date("N", mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)); // Starting day of current month
    $finish = date("N", mktime(0,0,0,$month,$days,$year)); // Finishing day of  current month
    $laststart = $start - 1; // Days of previous month in calander

    $counter = 1;
    $nextMonthCounter = 1;

    if($start > 5){ $rows = 6; }else {$rows = 5; }

    for($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++){
        echo '<tr class="week">';
        for($x = 1; $x <= 7; $x++){

            if(($counter - $start) < 0){
                $date = (($lastmonth - $laststart) + $counter);
                $class = 'class="blur"';
            }else if(($counter - $start) >= $days){
                $date = ($nextMonthCounter);
                $nextMonthCounter++;

                $class = 'class="blur"';

            }else {
                $date = ($counter - $start + 1);
                if($today == $counter - $start + 1){
                    $class = 'class="today"';
                }
            }


            echo '<td '.$class.'><span class="dayWrap">'. $date . '</span></td>';

            $counter++;
            $class = '';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    ?>
</table>
<div class="changeMonthLinks">
    <a class="col-xs-12" href="?now=<?php echo date('Y-m-d', $dtNow - 30*24*60*60); ?>">< Prev</a>
    <a class="col-xs-12 aright" href="?now=<?php echo date('Y-m-d', $dtNow + 30*24*60*60); ?>">Next ></a>
</div>
```

Comment: WOw!! you're brilliant!! Thank you!

However.... it detects as "today" the number of the day we are, ignoring what month we are. So this month the 17th appears as today, but if I display the month before, the 17th is still "today".

Comment: you can use $finish instead of $dtNow and only 1 day, instead of 30. The header you can replace with whatever you like, if you know how to use the date function.